# Validate approach for clearing notifications

Tags: firebase

Could you validate my approach for using Firebase to manage a user notification system?

Basically I want to have user specific channels as well as more general channels which hold notifications.  These notifications would appear on an intranet if the user has not viewed them before.

The idea being a server side action will update Firebase endpoints using the REST API either for a specific user or broadcast to everyone.  The specific user messages I can easily mark as read and therefore not show them again, its the general broadcast I am struggling slightly with.

I could add a flag(user ID) to the general broadcast to indicate its read but I am concerned about performance as the client would have to check historic broadcast messages for the existence of this flag.  I could add a user id to create a new endpoint which should be quicker.
e.g. /notification/general/  - contains the message, this triggers the client which then checks to see if /users/USERID/MessageID exists if it doesnt display the message and create this end point.

Is there something I am missing or is that the best approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are the messages always consumed in-order? If so you could have each client remember the ID of the last message it read in each public channel. You could then use "startAt" on the queue to limit it to only new messages.

If they're not consumed in order, then you'll need some way of storing data about which ones were read and which ones weren't. Perhaps you can have each message get sent out to everyone's personal queue, and then have each user remove read messages.

Comment: Interesting approach - I also considered having daily batches which meant I only had to read todays batch and compare to a list of read messages.

Comment: On reflection I will go for the last read ID, these are after all queues of messages and it makes sense to indicate where you are in the queue. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since there are already undividual user messages, why not just deliver the broadcasts to everyone individually (think email) rather than trying to store a single copy and figure out who read it.

To reduce bulk, you could store the message content separately, and simply store the ids in a user's queue. Then when they are viewed, you flag them per-user without any additional complexity.

At 100k of users receiving 100 messages a day including broadcasts, with a standard firebase ID (around 20 characters), that comes out to 210,000,000 characters a year (i.e. nothing for a database, and probably still far less than the actual bulk of storing the message body), assuming they never expire and get deleted.

Comment: Thats certainly the easiest and most logical approach but using the REST API wouldn't I have to do a single API call for each message / user?  Which would lead to scaling issues.